# Joint probability density function - limits of integration

Tags: integration, statistics

Trying to determine the value of c in a joint probability density function:

$f(x,y)=ce^{-x}$ if $x \ge 0, |y| < x $ (otherwise 0)

Clearly, the route to determining $c$ is through $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x,y) dx dy = 1$. However, I am struggling with defining correct limits of integration. What should they be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have that the pdf $f(x,y)$ equals $ce^{-x}$ whenever $x \ge 0$ and $-x < y < x$, and equals zero elsewhere.

$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x,y) \; dy \, dx =
\int_0^\infty \int_{-x}^x c e^{-x} \; dy \, dx = \cdots = 2c
$$